# How do I change "about 35 mins 20 sec ago" and "9.35 AM Apr 2nd" to today's date and 02-04-2019 respectively in python?

Tags: python-3.x, date

I have data like "about 35 mins 20 sec ago" and "9.35 AM Apr 2nd" in one of the columns. The problem is that almost every entry is unique but the format of the values is from above two.

I have tried a regex but I am not able to generalize for all the rows in the column.

```
t1 = t1.replace({'time_posted': '^about.*ago$'}, {'time_posted': '03-04-2019'}, regex=True)
```

I want the output as today's date and 02-04-2019 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use your regex to extract the values you need and then build up a correct string?

To correct the dates (never an easy task using the regular python libs), I would suggest to use the following:

https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html

as a really useful and powerful date/time manipulation library...

and then rebuild your string.

Comment: for the time being I converted all the values to the same format by the following code **'tstamp = project_na.replace({'time_posted': '^about.*ago$'}, {'time_posted':'10.04 AM Apr 4th'}, regex=True)'** but now the problem is how can i convert this to just the dates. I want just the dates in my column "time_posted".